# Why is the return type Unit used to describe operations that have no return value in Q#; as opposed to void or none?

Tags: q#

Why did Microsoft, when creating Q#, decide to use the keyword Unit instead of void or none, to describe methods that have no return value? Is there a reason for this, or did Microsoft just want to do something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions and operations in Q# are always tuple-in tuple-out.
Together with singleton–tuple equivalence (the principle that `'T` and `('T)` are the exact same type), this lets Q# represent things uniformly, with every function and operation taking exactly one input and returning exactly one output, each of which are tuples.

One consequence of this approach that we can write a function like `Composed<'T, 'U, 'V>(inner : ('T -> 'U), outer : ('U -> 'V)) : ('T -> 'V)`, confident that we can pass *any* function as `inner`, without thinking about how many arguments it takes.

For this design to be consistent, we need that a function or operation that "returns nothing" returns an empty tuple rather than no value at all. In many functional languages (including F#), the type of the empty tuple is called `unit` or `Unit`, following traditional notation in type theory. In Q#, we decided to follow that tradition to clarify the distinction between the value `()` and the type `Unit`.

Comment: http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/07/void-vs-unit.html has a good discussion of the difference between Unit and void that expands on what Chris says.

Comment: You're stating that there's a difference in () and Unit, and that the return type is Unit and not (). However, in Visual Studio Code, the IntelliSense for Q# is telling me that Unit "Represents a singleton type whose only value is ()" as stated in this screenshot taken from VSCode: https://app.box.com/s/bjywq8oxvqphfdkexzoot0wdemv0i11r

Comment: @AJ_4real, there is a difference between Unit and (): Unit is a type, and () is a value of that type. Think of it like Bool and true; Bool is a type, true is a value of that type. Bool has two possible values, of course, while Unit has only one.